# haskell check equality by function

Tags: haskell, equivalence

In haskell I can use

```
sortBy (comparing snd)
```

to sort by the second value in a tuple.

Is there an equivalent function for testing equivalency?
I've come up with this but maybe there is something in the standard library.

```
equalsBy :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Bool
equalsBy f x y = f x == f y
```

The end goal is to group a list of pairs by their second values. With this I can do

```
groupBy (equalsBy snd) pairs
```

instead of

```
groupBy (\x y -> (snd x) == (snd y)) pairs
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean, are you asking for a stable sort?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are looking for a slightly higher level function called [`on`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Data-Function.html#v:on):

```
> import Data.Function
> :t on
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
```

Well how do I use that?  Like this!

```
> :t ( (==) `on` snd )
( (==) `on` snd ) :: Eq b => (a, b) -> (a, b) -> Bool
```

So that means we want:

```
> groupBy ( (==) `on` snd) [ (1,3), (23,9), (42,9), (1,3), (48, 3), (18,18)]
[[(1,3)],[(23,9),(42,9)],[(1,3),(48,3)],[(18,18)]]
```

Yay!

EDIT:

I'd like to note how `comparing` relates to `on`.  It is just a specialized use of `on`!

```
> :t comparing
comparing      :: Ord a => (b -> a) -> b -> b -> Ordering
> :t (compare `on`)
(compare `on`) :: Ord b => (a -> b) -> a -> a -> Ordering
```

(notice the type variables are swapped, but you can see the types are identical)

Comment: Also, `(compare \`on\`)` is the same as `on compare`. It doesn't sound quite as nice, but maybe makes the argument order of `on` a little more explicit.